# Clear all text of active text editor of VS code

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm creating an extension for vs code and want to clear existing text from the document and replace it with new text. as of now, I'm able to delete selected content only. tried the different solution but didn't worked

```
function clearAllText(editor = vscode.window.activeTextEditor){
  if (!editor) {
    return;
  } 
  editor.edit(builder => {
    const cursorPos = editor.selection.anchor;
    builder.delete(editor.document.lineAt(cursorPos).range);
    });
    if(editor.document.lineCount>0){
      clearAllText();
    }
}
```

Any help will be appriciated.

Comment: construct a range from the first to the last character of the file and delete this range

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
await vscode.commands.executeCommand('editor.action.selectAll`);
await vscode.commands.executeCommand('editor.action.clipboardCutAction');
```

Just select it all and cut it.

If you want to use the `delete(Range)` method, then use the `editor.document.lineCount` property to know how many lines there are in your document.

```js
builder.delete(new Range(new Position(0, 0), new Position(editor.document.lineCount-1, 1000))));
```

[You could get the number of characters on the last line too.   `editor.document.lineAt(editor.document.lineCount-1).range.end.character);`]